# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Offline Data Synchronization in Mobile App

Tags: offline, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm working on Offline Data Synchronization using JSON Store in IBM MobileFirst.
I have gone through this site but still I need more info to complete this scenario.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_client_api.html

Suggest me from where should I start to complete this or is there any prerequisites to do work with this one.

Correct me if I'm wrong Offline data Sync concept only applying for No-SQL databases. Why because  i gone through this site https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/jsonstore/jsonstore-java-api/#sample which is dealing wth collections. 
Collections concept in there in NOSQL I think.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide some more context as to what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Namfo I'm just working offline data synchronization poc(proff of concept) just for demo purpose. As we have feature like offline data synchronization. I just want to demonstrate this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to sync with JSONStore for offline purposes there is a blog post here that demonstrates how to manage documents metadata with JSONStore, download documents from a remote location and read them locally.

If you need another example I can help you with that.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2014/12/22/managing-pdf-documents-hybrid-app-offline-availability/

Comment: It is good but I want sample CRUD operation with JSONstore. whenever user in offline data must be in JSONstore and if user in online data must be revert back to backend.

Comment: You could send a GET request to a server and see if you get a response to determine if you are online or not and from there you can use either use JSONStore or not. I will look into creating a sample app that demonstrates this but this can be a start for you.

Comment: Here is the link I just followed but it is dealing with JSONstore but there is no database connection How it will reflect data back to database becase there is no connection https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/jsonstore/jsonstore-java-api/#sample

Comment: In that example the database connection will be whatever the adapter is connected to. If you do not want to use adapters you will have to implement your own way to connect to your server such as custom REST calls. Regardless, the premise for connecting between offline and online data store should be the same.

Comment: I just want to know  we can use any database or Nosql Database for this offline sync.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/jsonstore/jsonstore-java-api/#sample I imported this code working for me all the thing I need to do is connect to DB and store data to db whenever app connected to internet.

Comment: Yes you can just send your payload (docs) to some rest service and have it handle it either by adding it to some database or web server. There is a SQL adapter that IBM MobileFirst provides

http://javatechig.com/ibm-worklight/creatin-a-sql-adapter-in-ibm-worklight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90063/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-marupu-and-namfo).

Comment: To complete this POC I need to work on RESTful webservices, HTTP Adapter and SQL adapters.

Comment: can we link two adapters in on application in mobilefirst.

Comment: waiting to hear your reply.

Comment: Sorry about the wait. Yes you can do this. You can chat with me if you have more questions.

Comment: Still I'm confusing from where I need to start to complete this, I just Import https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/jsonstore/jsonstore-java-api/#sample simply it is working but I want it to be done with database like we need to connect to any database and operations must be done during offline and online.